# How to make the IDEA to recognize Spock's with() method?

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, ide, spock

I write on Groovy and use Spock framework for testing.
Some time ago, IDEA completely supports Spock.
When I've writing the code inside feature (test method) in where-block something like this:

```
with(someObject) {
 intField == 1
 ...
}
```

IDEA correctly recognize the `someObject` and understand that `intField` is field of the object, also, it was offering me other fields of the object. So, inside Spock's `with()` block I've felt like inside any closure from DefaultGroovyMethods (`with{}`, `each{}`, `find{}`, etc.), but haven't need to use explicit `it` param.

(So, I's writing `with(someObject) { intField == 1 }` what is the same is `someObject.with { assert it.intField == 1 }`.

After a moment IDEA missed Spock's with() method support.
Now, it don't recognize the class of the parameter (ex. `someObject`) in think that it's object of `Object` class. Any fields inside closure don't be recognized. Explicit `it` usage didn't help.

[image]

After some IDEA update everything have repaired, but after reboot the problem has come back.

Does anybody know how to fix it??

I'm using the last version of the IDE - 2018.2

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this out with 2018.1 and have the same issue as you. I didn't run the code but I am fairly certain that the code would be recognized and executed. This to me looks like a bug with Intellij, and it might be worth it to submit a bug report in their ticket tracking system.